# How devise_token_auth session hold in Rails and React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, devise

I want to have and hold session data using devise_token_auth in Rails.

When I use `current_user` in controller, I can't hold 'current_user'.

I think it cause session problem.

But I couldn't catch how to resolve the problem.

Would you tell me where is problem??

**Gemfile**
(I use github_url because rails5.x has error when non use github_url)

```js
...

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth', github: 'lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth'

...
```

**app/model/user.rb**

```js
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable,
         :confirmable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

**config/initializers/devise_token_outh.rb**

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = false

  config.token_lifespan = 2.weeks

  config.token_cost = Rails.env.test? ? 4 : 10

  config.headers_names = {:'access-token' => 'access-token',
                          :'client' => 'client',
                          :'expiry' => 'expiry',
                          :'uid' => 'uid',
                          :'token-type' => 'token-type' }

end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :devise_controller?, except: [:new, :create]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :devise_controller?, raise: false
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/api/v1/works_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class WorksController < ApplicationController

      def index
        works = Work.all
        user = current_user

  ##################################################
     I can't catch current_user
#######################################

        render json: {
          user: user,
          works: works
        }, status: :ok
      end

      def show
        work = Work.find(params[:id])

        render json: {
          work: work
        }, status: :ok
      end

      def create
        work = Work.create(title: params[:title],
                           body: params[:body],
                           language: params[:language],
                           framework: params[:framework]
                          )

        render json: {
          work: work
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
      resources :works
      resources :contents do
        resources :articles, only: %i[index]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and I search `session.to_hash` with gem of `better_errors` and `binding_of_caller`

but

```
>> session.to_hash
=> {}
```

## PS

I try requiring `access-token`, `client` , `uid` with devise_tokens.

I changed requiring above params because I can't catch `access-token` and so on.

1, `access-token` ⇨ `tokens` because `tokens` exists rails log when use sign_in path in devise

2, `client` → `nill` because I can't catch this params

3, `uid` → this params could catched

But I can't use sessions.

I put change files.

**application.rb**

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  # before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :devise_controller?, except: [:new, :create]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :devise_controller?, raise: false
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:tokens, :client, :uid, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

**docker-compose log**

```
ruby_1      |   User Create (6.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("uid", "encrypted_password", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["uid", "kaito24262426gmailcom@yahoo.co.jp"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$12$0ORDh6f6I5ACN2ZN30CDaeRF6TDMBDBAtofAhOGGf/t4ogvcRl3L6"], ["name", "杉澤　海斗"], ["email", "kaito24262426gmailcom@yahoo.co.jp"], ["created_at", "2021-05-21 14:23:39.874034"], ["updated_at", "2021-05-21 14:23:39.874034"]]
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb:43
ruby_1      |    (6.9ms)  COMMIT
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb:43
ruby_1      |    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb:57
ruby_1      |   User Update (1.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["tokens", "\"{\\\"cvt17yUWbsBWDA1lLdfpLg\\\":{\\\"token\\\":\\\"$2a$10$dT2UaerYZlSdjnF7hTTaeu3A8erjOnzVlwWSp/KIdMCYSmMxP17De\\\",\\\"expiry\\\":1622816620}}\""], ["updated_at", "2021-05-21 14:23:40.042722"], ["id", 15]]
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb:57
ruby_1      |    (2.6ms)  COMMIT
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb:57
ruby_1      |   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ruby_1      |   ↳ /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/devise_token_auth-7d21928324aa/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:106
ruby_1      | Completed 200 OK in 2432ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 45.5ms)
```

Comment: your condition: `before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :devise_controller?` , but your `ApplicationController < ActionController::API` is not `::DeviseController`

Comment: thanks for comment!I don't know I should change `ApplicationController < ActionController::API` including `::DeviseController`. How can I change?like a `ApplicationController < ActionController::API::DeviseController`??

Comment: i just recommend that you should remove condition `if: :devise_controller?` for `:authenticate_user!`, BTW follow doc: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/controller_methods, the request headers must contains `access-token`, `client` & `uid` (and miss them, `current_user` be nil and `authenticate_user!` return 401) so i guess you miss those params.

Comment: I try catch `access-token` and so on. But I can't.would you see added PS?

Comment: following the doc: "The authentication headers required for each request will be available in the response from the previous request" -> so you can get them in `response.headers` (sign_in response). You can understand how the flow work by reading test cases: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/testing